# Next.js 13 keyboard shortcuts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

In a normal Next.js 13 app without the experimental app directory, you'd setup keyboard shortcuts something like this:

```ts
import { useCallback, useEffect } from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const handleKeyPress = useCallback((event: KeyboardEvent) => {
    console.log("Key pressed:", event.key);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyPress);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKeyPress);
    };
  }, [handleKeyPress]);
...
```

With the experimental app directory, I'd imagine that I should do something similar in `layout.tsx`. I can't do this since I need useEffect (client) and [the docs say](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/routing/pages-and-layouts#root-layout-required) "The root layout is a Server Component by default and can not be set to a Client Component."

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

within the layout.tsx you can use a 'use client' tag at the top of the page. what you can also do if you want to avoid this is use a client wrapper, e.g PageWrapper that you then wrap everything within the layout with this wrapper and have the wrapper be client side in which you could then have the listener, apply a context so its shared between all child elements and you should be good.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).